# Modifying Visual Studio Code Appearance for Selective Element Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to selectively modify the appearance of certain elements in Visual Studio Code without changing the entire theme.

Specifically, I want to add visual attributes to variables and functions to make them stand out during security code reviews in other parts of the code.

For instance, I would like to highlight all instances of the validateUserInput function in my codebase with a different background color or text color, while keeping the rest of the code in the current theme intact.

Is there a way to accomplish this level of selective styling in Visual Studio Code?

I've explored various extensions, but haven't found a solution that precisely fits this requirement. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you say various extensions you should named them, if you can't find one why not write it yourself

Comment: Did you look at the Highlight extension?